# Outlook add-in not showing in outlook menu after installing

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook-addin, add-in, installshield

I have created a setup file for outlook add-in using installShield. After building the setup project, it has given setup file, that I installed in my machine. But when I open the outlook it is not showing in add-in tab. I tried to search the disabled add-ins also, it was not there.
Please suggest me.

Comment: If I google for `Outlook add-in not showing in outlook menu after installing` I see lots of potential issues and solutions. Can you share with us which of those you have already tried?

Comment: Big possibility : there is an exception while starting your addin and outlook must disable it. You can check the list of addin active.

Comment: Do you see the registry entries created for your addin?

Comment: Thank you @DmitryStreblechenko 
Previously the add-in was not there in register entry. When I added the register data in register repository, The add-in displays in menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

By default, if a VSTO Add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear.

To show VSTO Add-in user interface errors you need to do the following steps:

1. Start the application.
2. Click the `File` tab.
3. Click `Options`.
4. In the categories pane, click `Advanced`.
5. In the details pane, select `Show VSTO Add-in user interface errors`, and then click OK.

See [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors) for more information.

Also I'd recommend choosing your own custom tab for the UI. Thus, you will be able to avoid any clashes with other add-ins.

VSTO provides two main ways for creating a custom tab:

- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer)
- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml)

Comment: In step 5 it should be "Developers" pane, not "Details" pane

Answer (score 0):

I missed the below step in InstallShield

I registered the Addin in Repository with the details of 
Description, Friendly Name, LoadBehaviour, and Manifest.
Now The add-in is showing in outlook menu bar.

[image]